# SQLite query to select one row and return it with 2 next rows

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

my database looks like this

```
ID      SSID      BSSID         RSSI
1.      ABCD      ab:cd:17      -68 
2.      efgh      cd:as:25      -60
3.      ijkl      cs:gb:d6      -75 
4.      abcd      dc:5g:f4      -72 
....
518.    ABCD      ab:cd:17      -68
519.    asfd      ag:4g:32      -60
520.    aasd      gd:5g:56      -79
```

I'm trying to create a function which selects row based on the input parameters of the function and return this row with 2 next rows.

What I've done so far is that the function returns the record with matching parameters.

```
public Cursor getRequiredData(String mac, int level){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("SELECT BSSID, RSSI FROM Scans_table WHERE BSSID =? AND RSSI =?", new String[] {mac, String.valueOf(level)});
    return res;
}
```

The result I'm looking for is, for example if `mac`parameter is `ab:cd:17` and `level = -68` the function returns rows 1, 2, 3  (sample data provided)

**EDIT:**

```
Cursor res = db.rawQuery("SELECT * from Scans_table st where ID >= " +
            "( select ID from Scans_table where BSSID =? AND RSSI =? ) order by st.ID asc limit 3 ", new String[] {mac, String.valueOf(level)});
```

This query works fine, but it just gives me the first record that matches `mac` and `String.valueOf(level)` parameters, and next 2 records with the highest `ID`. What if my table has more than one record with same values of these parameters? Is there a way to get all matching records and 2 nexts with highest ID?(sample data)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming by "next rows" you mean "rows with the next highest ids", you can use a subquery to get the id for the row you want and then `order by` and `limit` to get the next two rows:

```
select st.*
from scans_table st
where st.id >= (select st2.id from scans_table st2 where <your conditions are here>)
order by st.id asc
limit 3;
```

Comment: hi there, I didn't want to add a new questiong regarding the same query. I've just edited some part of it. If you could take a look that would be great.

Comment: @masoholic . . . You should ask a new question with appropriate sample data and desired results.  In particular, be specific about what to do in the case of duplicates particularly if the second id appears, say, 3 times.